# Getting WSO2 IOT Server running as a Windows Service

Tags: server, windows-server-2012, wso2, yajsw

I have installed WSO2 IOT Server on Server 2012R2. I installed YAJSW wrapper and configured it per WSO2 instructions. When I fire off runConsole.bat to configure the Windows service, I get the following error. I have JAVA_HOME & CARBON_HOME set. It looks like the process cannot find files, but the directory exists and there are files files there.

```
c:\Program Files\yajsw\bat>call setenv.bat
"java" -Xmx30m -Djna_tmpdir="c:\Program Files\yajsw\bat\/../tmp" -Djava.net.pref
erIPv4Stack=true -jar "c:\Program Files\yajsw\bat\/../wrapper.jar" -c "c:\Progra
m Files\yajsw\bat\/../conf/wrapper.conf"
YAJSW: yajsw-stable-12.08
OS   : Windows Server 2012 R2/6.3/amd64
JVM  : Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_121/C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121/64
Feb 23, 2017 8:09:07 AM org.apache.commons.vfs2.VfsLog info
INFO: Using "C:\Users\ADMINI~1.LEA\AppData\Local\Temp\1\vfs_cache" as temporary
files store.
WARNING|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-02-23 08:09:07|YAJSW: yajsw-stable-12.08
WARNING|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-02-23 08:09:07|OS   : Windows Server 2012 R2/6.
3/amd64
WARNING|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-02-23 08:09:07|JVM  : Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_
121/C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121/64
Feb 23, 2017 8:09:08 AM org.rzo.yajsw.wrapper.FileUtils getFiles
WARNING: No files found for C:\Program Files\WSO2\\bin\*.jar
system.env 55
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-02-23 08:09:08|started process with pid 638044
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-02-23 08:09:08|restart process due to default exit
 code rule
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-02-23 08:09:08|restart internal RUNNING
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-02-23 08:09:08|stopping process with pid/timeout 6
38044 45000
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-02-23 08:09:09|process exit code: 1
```

Comment: Ok, I resolved the first error, seems that CARBON_HOME needs to be one directory further "\broker". I got the service installed, but now it stops for this error: "restart process due to default exit code rule"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was using yajsw 12.08. And yajsw 11.11 has solved it. 
 
Download link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/yajsw/files/yajsw/yajsw-stable-11.11/

Comment: I have the same problem with WSO2 EI 6.0.0. For me yajsw 11.11 don't resolve the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648128/wso2-as-service-on-windows . Log from yajsw is the same as in this question? When trying to run "runConsole.bat"