# WSO2 as service on Windows

Tags: windows, service, wso2, yajsw

Need to install WSO2 API Manager as service on Windows (Have tried on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012. The problem is the same). 
Documantation: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service 
I am using yajsw. And when trying to run "runConsole.bat" for testing as it was said in the documatation I got such message/error:

```
D:\WSO2\yajsw-stable-12.08\yajsw-stable-12.08\bat>call setenv.bat 
"java" -Xmx30m -Djna_tmpdir="D:\WSO2\yajsw-stable-12.08\yajsw-stable-12.08\bat\/../tmp" -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar "D:\WSO2\yajsw-stable-12.08\yajsw-stable-12.08\bat\/../wrapper.jar" -c "D:\WSO2\yajsw-stable-12.08\yajsw-stable-12.08\bat\/../conf/wrapper.conf"       
YAJSW: yajsw-stable-12.08
OS   : Windows 7/6.1/x86
JVM  : Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_111/C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre_1.8.32bit/32
WARNING|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:22|YAJSW: yajsw-stable-12.08
WARNING|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:22|OS   : Windows 7/6.1/x86
WARNING|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:22|JVM  : Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_111/C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre_1.8.32bit/32
system.env 67
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:22|started process with pid 5056
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:22|restart process due to default exit code rule
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:22|restart internal RUNNING
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:22|stopping process with pid/timeout 5056 45000
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:23|process exit code: 1
system.env 67
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:28|started process with pid 1360
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:28|restart process due to default exit code rule
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:28|restart internal RUNNING
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:28|stopping process with pid/timeout 1360 45000
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:29|process exit code: 1
system.env 67
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:34|started process with pid 1996
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:34|restart process due to default exit code rule
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:34|restart internal RUNNING
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:34|stopping process with pid/timeout 1996 45000
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:35|process exit code: 1
system.env 67
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:40|started process with pid 4952
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:40|restart process due to default exit code rule
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:40|restart internal RUNNING
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:40|stopping process with pid/timeout 4952 45000
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:41|process exit code: 1
system.env 67
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:46|started process with pid 1176
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:46|restart process due to default exit code rule
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:46|restart internal RUNNING
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:46|stopping process with pid/timeout 1176 45000
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:47|process exit code: 1
system.env 67
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:52|started process with pid 4772
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:52|too many restarts 
INFO|wrapper|"WSO2 Carbon"|17-03-07 14:05:52|Shutting down Wrapper
```

CARBON_HOME - C:\wso2am-2.0.0 
JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

Comment: Can you include the output for when you execute runConsole.bat this out put looks like it is from setenv.bat?

Comment: It is output from "runConsole.bat" (call setenv.bat %wrapper_bat% -c %conf_file%).

Comment: I guess it is a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418330/getting-wso2-iot-server-running-as-a-windows-service

Comment: I am assuming based on documentation version that you are working on API Manager 1.10?  What is your CARBON_HOME value?  Attempting to reproduce and want to make sure I have settings as you do.

Comment: I am using wso2am-2.0.0. There is CARBON_HOME in the question now. Thank you for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the version of yajsw.  I used 11.11 and it works with no issue.  If I upgrade to use 12.08 I get the same result that you do.  I will attempt to find out what the actual issue is but wanted to let you know how you could get it working.  I will edit this post with any updates.

Joe

Comment: will try to change version. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

We use the [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/) (the Non-Sucking Service Manager) service wrapper for the WSO2 products. This works just perfectly for all products.

Just run the nssm.exe and point to the wso2server.bat file. See the [NSSM documentation](https://nssm.cc/commands) how easy it is.

```
nssm install <servicename>
```